# Laravel-4 1103 Incorrect table name 'users '

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a registration application in laravel and  I'm getting an incorrect syntax exception stating that the table 'users' doesn't exist/is invalid?

[image]

My User model class:

```
    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

relevant section of database.php config:

```
        'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'tforum',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

And this is how I am saving the data in db:

```
    $user   =   new User();
    $user->username =   Input::get('username');
    $user->password =   Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

    if($user->save())
```

The table 'users' exists in my database and I have migrated all created migrations so I don't understand why my 'users' table is incorrect, have I used an invalid naming convention for this table?

Comment: There is a space after the table name `users `

Comment: You should not have to declare the table name if it is the plural of the model name, which in your case it is. Try removing    `protected $table = 'users';` from the model.

Comment: @juergen good spotting! I have checked all possible places and each entry of 'users' is without a space, I have tried removing the table declaration in the model and still nothing. Anything else I could try?

Comment: Where is the code executing this query? As the create would be an insert not a count query.

Comment: It's executing in my UserController class (last code snippet) and just using the save() method to insert atleast that's what I thought it did, no idea why it's trying to COUNT()

Comment: Are you sure that the table name is correct in your actual database?